# How to reset all the notification permissions on macOS Ventura?

Tags: macos

I accidentally dismissed the notification permission request for the built-in Podcasts app, and it does not show up in the notification settings for whatever reason. Is there a way to reset all the notification permissions on macOS Ventura?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.